# Why doesn't my form Submit when I try to submit without using submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Below is my code to validate:

```
$(function () {
    function validateform() {
        // Code
    }
    $('#myform').submit(validateform);
});
```

And on action of this piece I want to submit this

```
<form id="myform" name="form"  action="http://www.google.com">
   // Form elements inputs, textarea 
   <div class="line"><span class="miss">Send Your Message</span>
</form>
```

Onclick of send your Message, the form should be submitted.

Comment: Do you want to submit your `<form />` by clicking `Send Your Message`?

Answer (score 1):

You're not firing the `submit` method. To fire the method you just need to call it without arguments: `$('#myform').submit()`. If you use the `submit` method with argument you're an just registering a event handler.

So you will need to modify your code with this:

```
$(function () {
  function validateform() {
      // Code
  }
  $('#myform').submit(validateform); // This will register an event handler.
  $('#myform').submit();             // This will trigger the submit event.
});
```

Please [see the docs for jQuery submit method](http://api.jquery.com/submit/).

---

**Edits**

Mike, if you want to just submit your `<form />` via the `<span />` you can do it writing this code:

```
$(function () {
  function validateform() {
      // Code
  }
  $('#myform').submit(validateform);

  $('span.miss').click(function() {
    $('#myform').submit();
  });
});
```

Comment: then how does this fiddle work without triggering submit:
http://jsfiddle.net/DaDQT/6/

Comment: The submit is triggered via the HTML submit button, but not programatically. In the JavaScript, you're just registering the event handler for the `onsubmit` event of the `<form />`. Then it is executed each time you press the HTML submit button.

Answer (score 0):

```
  function validateForm() {
      if (validation code) {
          $('form#myform').submit();
      } else {
          //display validation errors
          return false;
      }
  }

  $(function () {
      $('form#myform .miss').click(validateForm);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works basically and checks for space validation as well

```
$(function() {
            function validate() {
                var valid = true;
                $(".error").remove();
                $(".req").each(function() {
                    if($(this).val() == "" ||  $(this).val().replace(/\s/g, '').length == 0) {
                        $(this).after("<span class='error'>You should fill this field</span>");
                        valid = false;
                    }
                });
                return valid;

            }

                $('span.classofspantag').click(function() {
                $('#myform').submit(validate);
                    $('#myform').submit();
                });

        });
```